# How to prevent iTunes automatic backup before sync of iOS devices

Tags: itunes

Syncing your iOS device with iTunes can be pretty long since it always trigger a local backup to the computer.

How can you prevent this backup (that can be done manually at any time), and immediately start the sync process?

Answer (score 0):

Quit iTune and in the Terminal.app, simply type:
`defaults write com.apple.iTunes AutomaticDeviceBackupsDisabled -bool true` and press Enter.
Launch iTunes and voila!

Comment: Do you know how to do this on windows?